# Javascript (JQuery) remove last word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove the last word from an overflowing element until the element's content is not in overflow any longer.
I have tried this

```
var pageHeight = 25.7; //This is cm, but I can convert to px easily enough
var pageContent = "";
var d = $("<div />").appendTo('body');
function removeLast(d){
    //remove last word
    var str = $(d).html()
    var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
    var str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
    $(d).html(str);
    if ($(d).height() > pageHeight){
        removeLast(d);  //to try and loop around
    }
}
```

And this

```
$(d).html( trimSentence($(d).html()) );
if ($(d).height() > pageHeight){
    removeLast(d);
}
```

(The following came from another SO answer & seems to work fine)

```
function trimSentence(string){
var found = false;
var index = null;

var characterGroups = string.split(' ').reverse();

var position     = 1,//skip the first one since we know that's the end anyway
    elements     = characterGroups.length,
    element      = null,
    prevHadUpper = false,
    last         = null,
    lookFor      = '';

while(!found && position < elements) {
    element = characterGroups[position].split('');

    if(element.length > 0) {
       last = element[element.length-1];

       // test last character rule
       if(
          last=='.' ||                // ends in '.'
          last=='!' ||                // ends in '!'
          last=='?' ||                // ends in '?'
          (last=='"' && prevHadUpper) // ends in '"' and previous started [A-Z]
       ) {
          found = true;
          index = position-1;
          lookFor = last+' '+characterGroups[position-1];
       } else {
          if(element[0] == element[0].toUpperCase()) {
             prevHadUpper = true;
          } else {
             prevHadUpper = false;
          }
       }
    } else {
       prevHadUpper = false;
    }
    position++;
}


var trimPosition = string.lastIndexOf(lookFor)+1;
return string.substr(0,trimPosition);
}
```

But both appear not to work when the loop is in use, but work fine without the loop.
I am attempting to make the divs content be reduced in length until there is no overflow, and the 'overflowing' text should be copied into another string (but that is probably for another question)

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what you are trying to achieve? What is the big picture here? Why isn't it enough to style the element using CSS and hide the overflow?

Comment: I need to add the overflow to another 'page', in order to make all of the content visible to the user, but broken up into separate blocks

Answer (score 0):

use text() method instead of html():

```
var str = $(d).text()
```

html() contains the html markup but text() method contains only text strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using of `CSS` rule

```
word-wrap
```

From `docs`

```
The word-wrap CSS property is used to specify whether or not the browser 
may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow 
when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit in its containing box.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap